# Use interactive Jupyter notebook with ssh tunneling

Tags: python, ssh, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am currently using Python3 and ssh tunneling to use loc Jupyter GUI from remotely fired notebook.
I have an error when I run the following code:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../../../'))
```

The error:

```
---> 26 sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../../../'))

NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

This same code works when run directly on the remote server. But not in local browser.

Could somebody explain why this is happening pls?

Answer (score 0):

There is no variable `__file__` in jupyter notebook, because '**file**' applies to *modules and Python scripts*, not to notebooks.

You can use the following code to get path in notebook

```py
from pathlib import Path
cwd = Path().resolve()
sys.path.append(cwd.parent.parent.parent)
```